# Search for string within text column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

I have mysql table that has a column that stores xml as a string. I need to find all tuples where the xml column contains a given string of 6 characters. Nothing else matters--all I need to know is if this 6 character string is there or not.

So it probably doesn't matter that the text is formatted as xml.

Question: how can I search within mysql? 
ie 
`SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.xml [contains the text '123456']`

Is there a way I can use the LIKE operator to do this?

Comment: Refer this: http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/mysql-search/

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You could probably use the [`LIKE` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) to do some simple string matching:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.xml LIKE '%123456%'
```

If you need more advanced functionality, take a look at MySQL's fulltext-search functions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: .. how would I modify this to use with a PHP query? I have a string `$message` and I'd like to select the row with that exact string. I have `SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE from_id = '$fromID' AND to_id = '$toID' AND message LIKE '$message'` but I don't think that works

Comment: What if `123456` is the beginning of the string, then it wouldn't work.

Comment: timothymarois - the % matches zero or more characters, so it will work if the desired string is at the beginning, end, or middle of what you're searching in. See: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: You should probably [escape it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327092/how-should-i-escape-characters-inside-this-like-query) too.

Answer (score 12):

Using like might take longer time so use *full_text_search*:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE MATCH(items.xml) AGAINST ('your_search_word')
```

Comment: Is this proven to be faster than LIKE ?

Comment: It is important to note that for this to work one needs to have `FULLTEXT` index on the target column.

Comment: To further expand for others, FTS is very much so different than `LIKE` which will return variants of words and phrases, while FTS will not. eg. `LIKE '%123456%'` will return results with `"0123456", "123456", "1234567"`, etc. Where `AGAINST('123456')` will only return results as single words to *match against* such as `"is 123456", "123456", "123456 is"`, etc but *NOT* find `"0123456"` or `"1234567"`. Example:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5rJUTdDtV63RybnY4U9L2W/0 Which is why FTS can perform faster on larger datasets, as it is not performing a full table scan that occurs with `LIKE`.

Comment: This fails if there isn't a full text index against the column.

Answer (score 7):

Why not use LIKE?

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.xml LIKE '%123456%'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE `items.xml` LIKE '%123456%'
```

The `%` operator in `LIKE` means "anything can be here".

Answer (score 6):

you mean:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.xml LIKE '%123456%'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the wordpress prepare line, the above solutions do not work.  This is the solution I used:

```
   $Table_Name    = $wpdb->prefix.'tablename';
   $SearchField = '%'. $YourVariable . '%';   
   $sql_query     = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $Table_Name WHERE ColumnName LIKE %s", $SearchField) ;
 $rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql_query, ARRAY_A);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try function LOCATE. Better than LIKE since you don't need to massage the argument.
Example (python):

```
cursor.execute('select columns from table where locate(%s,haystack)>0', (needle,))
```