# MySQL LIKE vs LOCATE

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know which one is faster:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%text%';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOCATE('text',column)>0;
```

Comment: Why not benchmark/profile this and find out?

Comment: @matro:what is benchmark/profile .just for enthu

Comment: Like should be faster. A fulltext index and `match against` will be much faster.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Added April 20th, 2015: Please read also [Hallie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22058120/402253) below

---

First one but marginally. Mostly because it doesn't have to do an extra `> 0` comparison.

```
mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000,LOCATE('foo','foobar'));
+---------------------------------------------+
| BENCHMARK(100000000,LOCATE('foo','foobar')) |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                           0 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (3.24 sec)

mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000,LOCATE('foo','foobar') > 0);
+-------------------------------------------------+
| BENCHMARK(100000000,LOCATE('foo','foobar') > 0) |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               0 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (4.63 sec)


mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000,'foobar' LIKE '%foo%');
+--------------------------------------------+
| BENCHMARK(100000000,'foobar' LIKE '%foo%') |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          0 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (4.28 sec)


mysql> SELECT @@version;
+----------------------+
| @@version            |
+----------------------+
| 5.1.36-community-log |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: How does `benchmark` works, What's the accuracy of these numbers?

Comment: `BENCHAMRK` is simply running the provided expression a given number of times. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-benchmarking.html 
As for accuracy I can't really tell you much. I found it to be pretty good when it comes to precision though.

Answer (score 6):

+1 to @Mchl for answering the question most directly.

But we should keep in mind that neither of the solutions can use an index, so they're bound to do table-scans.

Trying to decide between a cloth or plastic adhesive bandage is kind of silly, when you're trying to patch the hull of the Titanic.

For this type of query, one needs a [full-text search index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html). Depending on the size of the table, this will be [hundreds or thousands of times faster](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

Comment: The problem with full-text in MySQL is that it is not currently capable of wildcard search, only prefix search (`foo*` will match `foobar`, but `*bar` won't).

Comment: Apache Lucene and  Solr have the same limitation. Sphinx Search supports infix indexing, so you can put wildcards at the start of a pattern. See http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-min-infix-len.html

Answer (score 4):

I did some tests as Mchi did.And I think it's hard to say which one is faster. It looks like  depending on the first occurrence of the substring.

```
mysql> select benchmark(100000000, 'afoobar' like '%foo%');
+----------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(100000000, 'afoobar' like '%foo%') |
+----------------------------------------------+
|                                            0 |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (9.80 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(100000000, locate('foo', 'afoobar'));
+------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(100000000, locate('foo', 'afoobar')) |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                              0 |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (8.08 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(100000000, 'abfoobar' like '%foo%');
+-----------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(100000000, 'abfoobar' like '%foo%') |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                                             0 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (10.55 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(100000000, locate('foo', 'abfoobar'));
+-------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(100000000, locate('foo', 'abfoobar')) |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               0 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (10.63 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(100000000, 'abcfoobar' like '%foo%');
+------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(100000000, 'abcfoobar' like '%foo%') |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                              0 |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (11.54 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(100000000, locate('foo', 'abcfoobar'));
+--------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(100000000, locate('foo', 'abcfoobar')) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (12.48 sec)

mysql> select @@version;
+------------+
| @@version  |
+------------+
| 5.5.27-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```