# Which is better? Locate or like % in the where clause of a Mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL LIKE vs LOCATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499438/mysql-like-vs-locate)

I need to write a Mysql  query which chooses rows based on a string in a column. Say the column is named TestColumn. I need to choose all rows which contain 'stackoverflow' anywhere in the column. Would it better to use

```
Select * from testtable where TestColumn like '%stackoverflow%'
```

or

```
Select * from testtable where Locate('stackoverflow', TestColumn)>0
```

Which would result in a better performance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499438/mysql-like-vs-locate

Comment: Both prevent the use of indexes, so they're going to be painfully slow on large tables either way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

% is better than a function call. % will use full text index if it is existing. It is not the case with the function call.

Comment: LIKE is a function call.

Comment: Not quite, LIKE does NOT use a full-text index. It might in some cases use a normal index, but not a full-text one.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a problem for `LIKE`.  `LOCATE` should be used when the position of the substring is important.