# How to find an exact string within a mysql column

Tags: mysql

I have a question, what is the best way to find an exact string match within a column.

I tried using `locate('needle', 'haystack') > 0.` The problem with this is, for instance if the string I am trying to find is something like 'Ed', but inside a blob or a text column, I have a string that says 'I lived', locate() would return 6. However, this is not what I am asking. In an exact match, it would be best to use `LIKE ''`, however, LIKE has it's performance issues, therefore, it is not a viable solution.

Is there a way I an use `LOCATE()` to do an exact match?

Comment: You say LIKE has performance issues, but you're not going to solve the performance issue by using a function that does exactly what LIKE does.

Comment: What performance problems are you experiencing with `LIKE` that you aren't experiencing with `LOCATE`? Both methods will obfuscate any indexes, so they should perform relatively the same - [and based on this answer, `LIKE` marginally out-performs `LOCATE`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7500150/643591).

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
WHERE CONCAT(' ', column, ' ') LIKE BINARY '% string_to_find %'
```

or using LOCATE:

```
WHERE LOCATE(BINARY ' Ed ', CONCAT(' ', column, ' '))
```

Using BINARY will force an exact case matching. I think that performance of LOCATE or LIKE will be very similar. Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8eb11/2).

Comment: Thanks! This actually works. I wasn't sure how to concatenate white spaces around the column value. This gives me a higher probability of finding a match.

Thanks again.