# Search/Querying a mysql database with a keyword with partial match being OK

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
public function search($search)
{
    global $pdo;
    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_name = ?');
    $query->bindValue(1, $search);
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

with that function if I called it, and say `$search` was `cookie`.

and inside my database I have

```
chocolate chip cookie
oatmeal cookie
cookie
```

it would only return `cookie` So how could I fix my query so it returns all the `item_name`s that are a partial match or contain cookie also? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, or as an alternative to `LIKE`, you could use [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) or [`INSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_instr):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOCATE('cookie', item_name);
```

**Note:** If you're curious about performance, here's some [old benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499438/mysql-like-vs-locate).

Comment: If you need word boundaries, you can use `CONCAT()` as shown in **Gordon Linoff**'s answer.

Comment: Oh my gosh, this is so great. I've been looking for something like this all morning.

Answer (score 3):

You would use [`like`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
where item_name like '%cookie%'
```

If you want to look for a full word match:

```
where concat(' ', item_name, ' ') like '% cookie %'
```

Comment: could I do `WHERE item_name LIKE %?%` or how would that work if I'm binding it?

Comment: That should work, although you need the single quotes around the pattern.

Comment: `$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_name LIKE '%?%'");` would be good?