# get the maximum number that extracted from a string using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, string, substring

I have a table called Elements

```
id    reference
101   AES/JN/2001
102   AMES/JN/2001
103   AES/JN/2002
104   AES/JN/2003
105   AMES/JN/2002
```

I want to get the maximum number from the string. If my search key word is AMES/JN I should get 2002. And If my key word is AES/JN then output should be 2003

I have tried the following code:

```
select max(convert(substring_index(reference,'/', -1), unsigned)) as max
        FROM Elements  WHERE reference like 'AES/JN/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check how "[LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)" work's.
You can use % as joker

Just change your query and add % character. And it's work

```
    SELECT
    max(
        CONVERT (
            substring_index(reference, '/', - 1),
            UNSIGNED
        )
    ) AS max
FROM
    reference
WHERE
    reference LIKE 'AES/JN/%'
```

Please note : `LIKE 'AES/JN/%'`

Answer (score 2):

I almost agree with Shyam except for that horribly convoluted function.

I recommend this query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(reference,'/',-1) as `max`
FROM `Elements`
WHERE reference LIKE 'AES/JN/%'
ORDER BY reference DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This will output a single row with with `2003` as the value in the `max` column.

The reason I like this method is because `CONVERT()` is omitted/unnecessary.

I've compared my query against Xenofexs' on my server and mine is only `.0001` seconds faster -- but this is only running on the 5 rows that the OP posted. As the database volume increases, I am confident that my query's performance lead will increase.

Even if you don't care about the micro-optimization, I think this query is easier to read/comprehend because it doesn't have a function inside a function inside a function.

---

In fact, I believe this next query may outperform my above query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(reference,'/',-1) as `max`
FROM `Elements`
WHERE LOCATE('AES/JN/',reference)
ORDER BY reference DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Because `LOCATE()` will be checking the leading characters from the `reference` column, and the targeted substring will not occur later in the string, `LOCATE()` has been benchmarked to outperform `LIKE`.

Additional reading:
[MySQL LIKE vs LOCATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499438/mysql-like-vs-locate)

---

For the record, here is the table that I used:

```
CREATE TABLE `Elements` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Elements` (`id`, `reference`) VALUES
(101, 'AES/JN/2001'),
(102, 'AMES/JN/2001'),
(103, 'AES/JN/2002'),
(104, 'AES/JN/2003'),
(105, 'AMES/JN/2002');

ALTER TABLE `Elements`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `Elements`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=106;
```

Comment: You should use the `LIKE` solution, and add an index on the `reference` column. The index will help the `LIKE` perform faster, and it will also help the `ORDER BY`. The LOCATE() solution cannot use an index and it will force a table-scan. Use EXPLAIN to confirm this.

Comment: P.S. [Don't use MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17706717/20860). :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(Z.COUNT),reference FROM
(
  SELECT reference,CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(reference, '/', -1) AS DECIMAL) count 
  FROM Elements where reference like 'AES/JN/%'
)Z
```

Try above code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do comment ,if you are down voting some one..!!

Comment: I didn't downvote this one, but whom ever did probably did so because you are using a subquery when the desired result can be achieved without one.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes got it.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below solution.

Query:

```
select id,reference,digits(reference) as num_values from asasas where reference like 'AMES/JN%' order by num_values DESC limit 1
```

You need to create one function in mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test`.`digits`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `digits`( str CHAR(32) ) RETURNS char(32) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE c CHAR(1);
  IF str IS NULL
  THEN 
    RETURN "";
  END IF;
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str );
  REPEAT
    BEGIN
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 );
      IF c BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c);
      END IF;
      SET i = i + 1;
    END;
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT;
  RETURN ret;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Let me know if it not works for you