# mysql_real_escape_string is undefined

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I am using PHP version 5.3 and trying to use `mysql_real_escape_string($unescaped_string)` in my code, but I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() 
in /var/www/engine/database.php on line 38
```

I can still connect to the database however.  Why is it not available?

I am using PHP version 5.3.

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Try mysql_escape_string() instead

Comment: @jtheman why are you suggesting replacement of better function (that takes server configuration into account) with worse function (just simple string replace)?

Comment: How did you know that you can get database

Comment: @Vyktor Sure it's better. But its not certain the user can change his server config.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() was created because mysql_escape_string() has vulnerabilities, would strongly advise not to use it!

Comment: The problem with `mysql_real_escape_string()` is it requires a connection to the DB to determine the character set.  Unfortunately you could very well have a program which needs to escape strings but doesn't have a way to get a connection to the DB (eg a program which creates a file in INSERT statements which is then transported to the DB machine to be acted upon).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update** as mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856639/mysql-real-escape-string-is-undefined/13856694?noredirect=1#comment58761215_13856694), `mysql_` has been [deprecated since 5.5](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql):

> The mysql extension has been deprecated since PHP 5.5. The mysqli or PDO extension should be used instead. The deprecation has been decided in [mysql_deprecation](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), where a discussion of the reasons behind this decision can be found.

and **removed in PHP 7**.

---

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is standard part of [MySQL function "batch"](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) and should always work if the extension is loaded correctly.

Does any another `mysql_` function work? (It should not)

Make sure, that you have this line uncommented in your `php.ini`:

```
extension=mysql.so
```

Also it'd be wise to use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead ([`mysql_` is deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799)), they both can take care of escaping for you.

Comment: Sorry, this question was my fault. When I used the sudo apt-get install php5-mysql it failed, and I thought that my other connect statement was working properly. I guess you just got yourself a free correct answer.

Comment: @MichaelH it takes some practice to check system configuration first (after update) before wondering what's wrong with your code.

Comment: The MySQL extension is [not available since PHP 5.5](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7); use ext/mysqli or ext/pdo_mysql instead.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I used `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, after exploring all the other solutions here, I realized the problem is actually due to the `php5-mysql` extension not having been installed yet - it's not installed by default on a fresh Ubuntu, neither when u install fresh php. So, for me the solution became: install the php5-mysql extension:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

After this, I wasn't getting those nasty mysql_* errors again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL extension is deprecated since PHP 5.5. mysql_real_escape_string() is therefore not available in PHP 7. This means that user input cannot be escaped correctly and leaves the code open to SQL injection attacks.

The PHP-official solution is to [replace ext/mysql with MySQLi, PDO](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7) or other supported database extension.

To prevent SQL injection attacks, it is recommended to use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) when talking to the database.

Comment: Any database API that's available (mysql, mysqli, PDO, whatever) has a function to escape values correctly or to use the prepared statement API of the database directly (much better approach to begin with). If `real_escape_string` or equivalent is not available that means the entire database API is not available and you have much bigger problems anyway. There should never be a need to poorly reimplement this function. Critically you're not implementing any encoding concerns, which still leaves you open to injection in certain multi-byte encodings.

Comment: @deceze: Answer changed to focus on the "MySQL extension is deprecated" part. Removed function that mimics `mysql_real_escape_string()`.