# Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql

//Here is the code from insert.php

---

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if(isset($_POST['image']) &&  isset($_POST['cate']) ){

```
        $image = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['image']));

        $cate = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['cate']));



        $query_input = "INSERT INTO category(cat_name,image) VALUES('$cate','$image')";
        $result_input = insert_fun($query_input);
```

Comment: Are you using PHP 7? Then it is removed. You can't use it. If not [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13856694/5447994)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_real\_escape\_string is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13856694/5447994)

Comment: @Thamilan yes I'm using php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
$value = trim($_POST['image']);
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $value);
mysqli_close();
```

Since new php version mysqli is used instead of mysql.
Notice the letter "i".
Where $link stands for the mysqli_connect.