# How to search string in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search number in my MySQL data. String is +310623212542 but the mysql row data is only 0623212542. How can i compare ? Please help i am new to the mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for string within text column in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526772/search-for-string-within-text-column-in-mysql)

Comment: use `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE search = SUBSTRING('+310623212542' FROM 4)`

Comment: in php `<?php $search_text = substr('+310623212542',3); mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE search LIKE '%$search_text%'");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

**In php**

```
<?php 
$search_text = substr('+310623212542',3);
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE search LIKE '%$search_text%'");
?>
```

or

**in mysql**

use `SUBSTRING`

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE search = SUBSTRING('+310623212542' FROM 4)
```

Note: using substring in mysql impact performance issue, when large data present