# Search multiples strings in MySQL in a text colunm separated by ","

Tags: java, mysql

I didn't found a solution for my problem.

Here's a example:

A have a Table, for example: `Person`. And it has a column that contains alot number separated by ",". These numbers represent things, but it isn't relevant right now.

Table `Person`:

```
nm_name: Jonas
nm_email: jonas@example.com
ds_numbers: 1,2,3,5,17,27,67,77,
```

I want to make a query that filter the searchs in table person by this column `ds_numbers`. But the user will select witch numbers will by the filter, for example, if user select at least 1 number that is in this column, the register will come.

If I select, for example, "3" this register will come, or "3,55,12" will come too, because at least 1 value need to be in string.

The problem it, I can't use Like '%4%' because I would return 4, 41, 74... Any different solutions?

**Important:** I mount this query in Java, so I can use Java features, like Loops, but I didn't found a solution. Any ideas?

And I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LIKE, but with the current format, you will get false positives.  '%4%' will also match the number 40, or 14.

Ideally, change your data to store the numbers with a delimiter.  "|3|,|55|,|32|".
Then when you select using LIKE '%|3|%', it will only match the |3|.

You could use LIKE '%3,%', but that won't match the last number if 3 is the very last number in the string.

Comment: I thought about it, to use '%', it really would not work. But I liked your solution to use the "|". Sure would work but have a giant base already populated, it is not feasible. But thanks for sharing!

Comment: Do your fields have a trailing comma at the end?  (in your example, you have one, but it may just be a snippet.)  If not, can you add a trailing comma to the fields?  if so, then you could use LIKE '%,3,%' or LIKE '%,343,%'

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with a simple text search using wildcards with the LIKE operator.

```
SELECT ds_numbers FROM table WHERE ds_numbers LIKE '%3%'
```

If not then you can try the fulltext-search capabilities as mentioned in the answer for this question: [Search for string within text column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526772/search-for-string-within-text-column-in-mysql)