# How to search for unexact keyword in SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am Trying to create a search bar to search for a Title that is stored in the table already using php. To find the title I have to input the exact title ex. Input: (Title) Output: (Title). I want it so all you have to do is type a part of the word and the query filters for the titles with those words: Input: (tle) Output: (Title, First_Title). Is this possible to do with the query or do I have to use something else? The $Unexact variable is the variable used as the input.

```
$name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM information WHERE Title='".$UnExact."'") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
```

Comment: Why are you using "mysql_"?  It is deprecated.  Use `mysqli_`.

Comment: `LIKE '%$UnExact%'`

Comment: I would use ILIKE '%$UnExact%' case insensitive, just in case (pun intended :D)

Comment: Oh wait you are using MySQL, which has no ILIKE I'm used to PostgreSQL. I still suggest a case insensitive match however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for string within text column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526772/search-for-string-within-text-column-in-mysql)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/how-can-i-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard

Answer (score 1):

Try this (using mysqli extension)

```
$name = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM information WHERE LOWER(Title) LIKE '%". strtolower ($UnExact) ."%'");
```